# Mouse is flickering in new debian install

Tags: debian, drivers

I initially thought this might be a display driver issue but after installing the proprietary ATI drivers and now the free ones I am still getting it.

My mouse disappears when I scroll or write sometimes (but not always). It also flickers when I move, especially when I am in the `system settings` menu hovering over icons (it is only visible when I move the mouse, and even then it flickers a lot).

I did a search and this seems to be a common problem. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360423/mouse-cursor-flickering-and-disappearing) for ubuntu suggests removing an unknown monitor, but I only have 1 monitor that I can't remove. [This post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1522028&page=2&p=9536975#post9536975) suggests the problem is `unclutter`, which I don't have installed. Besides, the mouse disappearing doesn't seem to be time-related.

Any suggestions? I'm new to linux so I don't know what information I should be providing about my system. I'm running Debian Wheezy with a USB mouse. I have tried attaching it to the PC's usb port as well as a USB hub, without any change. It's a fresh install and this problem has existed since the first boot.

Comment: Does it happen with a different mouse? Is this a desktop? If not, does it happen with the touchpad? Which desktop environment are you using? Does it happen in others?

Comment: @terdon 64-bit PC. Tried a different mouse, same thing. I'm using Gnome classic. Tried logging into "Gnome" which looks the same (!?) and same problem. One interesting observation is that it doesn't occur when I first log in, only once I open up system settings or a browser, then it flickers even if I click around in the desktop menus (on first log in it doesn't flicker when I click on those menus).

Comment: @terdon just installed those proprietary drivers again as per the suggestions from my other question and it seems to be working now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the proprietary ATI drivers again seems to have fixed it...